# Wordpress submit_button(); to a new page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have this code:

```
function my_main_function()
{
    add_menu_page('MyNewPlugin', 'MyNewPlugin', 'manage_options', 'my_plugin_options', 'wps_theme_func');
}
    add_action('admin_menu', 'my_main_function');


function wps_theme_func()
{
    echo '
        <div class="wrap">
            <div id="icon-options-general" class="icon32"><br></div>
            <h2>Main Page</h2>
        </div>
    ';  

    submit_button('Add data', 'secondary');
}
```

How can I open a new page using the **Add data** button?

The page should appear in the same place as the **Main Page**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*submit_button* does not have a possiblity to redirect to another page.

But you can check for a hidden input-element and do a manual redirect in the init-action:

```
function wps_theme_func()
{

    echo '
        <div class="wrap">
            <div id="icon-options-general" class="icon32"><br></div>
            <h2>Main Page</h2>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="wps_theme_do_redirect" value="true">
    ';  

    submit_button('Add data', 'secondary');
}

add_action('init', 'wps_theme_init');

function mywps_theme_init() {
    if(isset($_POST['wps_theme_do_redirect'] && $_POST['wps_theme_do_redirect'] == 'true') {
        wp_redirect('options.php');
        exit();
    }
}
```

don't forget to warp the output of wp_theme_func() with a form-element.

edit: of course you can use the form-attribute as redirection:

```
function wps_theme_func()
{
    echo '
        <div class="wrap">
            <div id="icon-options-general" class="icon32"><br></div>
            <h2>Main Page</h2>
        </div>
        <form action="admin.php?page=page-b" method="post">
    ';  

    submit_button('Add data', 'secondary');

    echo '</form>';
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't seem to work. When the button is pressed is it supposed to set $_POST['submit'] ?

Comment: @Mrlx yes. The [Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/submit_button) says, that submit_button() will generate a HTML input-element with the name-attribute "submit" and the form should be submitted via POST. Maybe you do not have a form-tag? Have a look at the [example for custom admin pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus#Sample_Menu_Page).

Comment: I've wrapped it into a form and now I am getting this warning:"Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent " If I try to put it in the action='options.php' it says that I don't have enough rights to do that operation.

Comment: I updated the example above. you have to do the redirect in a separate function, sorry.

Comment: Ok, this is helpful so far but I encounter another problem. The redirect takes me to the /wp-admin page where it asks me to login again.

Comment: That's strange. Which should be the destination of your redirect or how do you call wp_redirect?

Comment: I'm sure I'm doing something wrong somewhere so I'll tell you exactly what I am trying to achieve. I have this admin menu with Page A and Page B. Each page has a "widefat" table on it that should display some data. There is also a button there "Submit Data" that I want to use. That button should take me to a page that has the field where I can input the data that it's supposed to appear in the "widefat" table. See this image: http://i.imgur.com/VsahW6x.gif

Comment: If you don't have any other input-elements except the submit-button, you can use the form for the redirect too. I've updated the answer above.